# accessing a method using a vector iterator

Tags: c++, methods, vector

I have two C++ objects. The first of which holds a vector of the second declared with:

```
std::vector<WormCell> cells;    // The dynamic array of the worms cells
```

In a method in the first I'm trying to use an iterator to go through the vector and call methods in the second but I'm getting an error. The code to call the method is:

```
void Worm::drawWorm(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    for (std::vector<WormCell>::iterator it = cells.begin() ; it != cells.end(); ++it)
    {
        sf::Vector2f pos = it->getPosition;
        circle.setPosition(pos);
    }
}
```

The error is:

*Error: A pointer bound to a function may only be used to call the function.*

which occurs on the *it->getPosition.*

How can I access the methods in cells using the iterator?

Comment: A *call* in C++ is called a *call* because it includes a function *call* operator `()`. Where is the function call operator in your `it->getPosition` line??? And if there's no function call operator there, why are you calling it a *call* at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function as if it was a data member.

Don`t forget the paranthesis. Try:

```
it->getPosition()
```

instead of

```
it->getPosition
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function requires a parameter list:

```
it->getPosition();
               ^^
```